# Gremlin query to check the cycle nature of the graph

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I am new to `gremlin`. I have task where I need to check the `cycle` nature of the vertex in the graph and return the output in either of the format `String` or `Boolean`:

```
{'crn': 'COMPANY_X', 'cycle': 'Y'}
{'crn': 'COMPANY_X', 'cycle': 'N'}
 or 
{'crn': 'COMPANY_X', 'cycle': true}
{'crn': 'COMPANY_X', 'cycle': false}
```

I have written a query with my little knowledge, which is throwing `MalformedQueryException`. There could be multiple errors. I am trying for the `String` output as mentioned above.

```
g.
  V('COMPANY_X').as('crn')
  .map(
    repeat(
    outE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO')
    .by(constant('N')).as('cycle')
    .inV()
    .simplePath())
    .until(not(outE()))
    .where(out().as('crn'))
    .by(constant('Y')).as('cycle')
  .select('crn', 'cycle')
  .project('crn', 'cycle')
    .by(id)
    .by(select(keys).select('cycle'))
  .fold()
  .V('COMPANY_X').as('crn')
  .map(
    repeat(
    outE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO')
    .by(constant('N')).as('cycle')
    .inV()
    .simplePath())
    .until(not(outE()))
    .where(out().as('crn'))
    .by(constant('Y')).as('cycle')
  .select('crn', 'cycle')
  .project('crn', 'cycle')
    .by(id)
  .by(select(keys).select('cycle'))
  .fold()
  .aggregate('x')
  .unfold()
```

Can you please guide me where I am going wrong?

I am trying to look for 2 types of `edges` i.e. `HAS_VOTING_PC_TO` or `HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO`. If I find the same `vertex`. I change the value of `cycle` field to `Y`. At the beginning it is set as `N`

Any leads would be really helpful to me. Thank you.

Comment: Probably you want to combine the cyclicpath() and choose() steps

Comment: If you could edit the question to include a few `addV` and `addE` steps that build a small sample graph, that would be very helpful, and make it easier to provide tested answers.

Comment: Thanks @HadoopMarc and @Kelvin, I am able to develop the query based on the answer provided here

https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#cycle-detection


```
g.V().as('a').repeat(both().simplePath()).emit(loops().is(gt(1))).
both().where(eq('a')).path().
dedup().by(unfold().order().by(id).dedup().fold())

```

Comment: Hello @KelvinLawrence, I developed a version of query for cycle detection. It is working for few cases but not returning anything for few simple scenarios. Would you like to have look at the query and suggest possible problem with it. The link -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77639728/gremlin-query-for-cycle-detection-works-for-complex-graph-but-returns-nothing-fo/77641268#77641268

Comment: Hello @HadoopMarc, I developed a version of query for cycle detection. It is working for few cases but not returning anything for few simple scenarios. Would you like to have look at the query and suggest possible problem with it. The link -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77639728/gremlin-query-for-cycle-detection-works-for-complex-graph-but-returns-nothing-fo/77641268#77641268