# gremlin query for cycle detection works for complex graph but returns nothing for simple one

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I have a gremlin query to detect cycle nature of the graph. I have tested it with multiple large complex graph it works as expected. But it does not return anything with simple 1 depth graph.

Could you please have a look at the query and help me in correcting the same.

```
g
 .V('RESTOX0').as('crn')
 .map(
  repeat(
  outE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO')
 .inV()
 .where(
      and(
        hasNot('superseded_dt'),
        or(has('status', 'active'), hasNot('status'))))
 .simplePath())
 .emit(loops().is(gt(1)))
 .both('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').choose(where(eq('crn')),
  sack(assign).by(constant('Y')),
  sack(assign).by(constant('N')))
 .select('crn')
 .project('crn', 'cycle')
  .by(id)
  .by(sack()))
 .fold()
 .V('RESTOX0').as('crn')
 .map(
  repeat(
  outE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO')
 .inV()
 .where(
      and(
        hasNot('superseded_dt'),
        or(has('status', 'active'), hasNot('status'))))
 .simplePath())
 .emit(loops().is(gt(1)))
 .both('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').choose(where(eq('crn')),
  sack(assign).by(constant('Y')),
  sack(assign).by(constant('N')))
 .select('crn')
 .project('crn', 'cycle')
  .by(id)
  .by(sack()))
 .fold()
 .aggregate('x')
 .dedup()
 .unfold()
```

The graph for which it does not work is created as below:-

```
%%gremlin
g.addV('company').property(id,'RESTOX0').property('name','Alphabet').next()
g.addV('person').property(id,'RESTOX0_1900-01-01_1_1').property('bu_id', 'RESTOX0_1900-01-01_1_1').property('name', 'W Karl David Laxton').next()
g.addV('person').property(id,'RESTOX0_1900-01-01_1_2').property('bu_id', 'RESTOX0_1900-01-01_1_2').property('name', 'Steven H Strong').next()

g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('RESTOX0')).to(__.V('RESTOX0_1900-01-01_1_1')).property(id,'RESTOX0_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_RESTOX0_1900-01-01_1_1').property('perc_value', 25).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('RESTOX0')).to(__.V('RESTOX0_1900-01-01_1_1')).property(id,'RESTOX0_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_RESTOX0_1900-01-01_1_1').property('perc_value', 50).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('RESTOX0')).to(__.V('RESTOX0_1900-01-01_1_2')).property(id,'RESTOX0_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_RESTOX0_1900-01-01_1_2').property('perc_value', 25).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('RESTOX0')).to(__.V('RESTOX0_1900-01-01_1_2')).property(id,'RESTOX0_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_RESTOX0_1900-01-01_1_2').property('perc_value', 25).next()
```

The expected output is as below as it is not a cycle scenario:

```
{'crn': 'RESTOX0', 'cycle': 'N'}
```

For cyclic case, the output should be:

```
{'crn': 'COMPANY0', 'cycle': 'Y'}
```

However, it does not return any output at all. Could you please help me with the issue in the query. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without deep diving into your query seems that the issue is on the `emit` step.

which in the small loop case returns nothing.

You can remove the condition from the `emit` and move it to the `choose` step like this:

```
g.V('RESTOX0').as('crn').
  map(repeat(outE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').inV().
      where(and(
          hasNot('superseded_dt'),
          or(
            has('status', 'active'),
            hasNot('status')
          )
        )).
      simplePath()).
    emit().
    both('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').choose(
      where(eq('crn')),
      sack(assign).
        by(constant('Y')),
      sack(assign).
        by(constant('N'))
    ).
      select('crn').
    project('crn', 'cycle').by(id).by(sack())).
  fold().V('RESTOX0').as('crn').
  map(repeat(outE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').inV().
      where(and(
          hasNot('superseded_dt'),
          or(
            has('status', 'active'),
            hasNot('status')
          )
        )).
      simplePath()).
    emit().
    both('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').choose(
      where(eq('crn')).where(loops().is(gt(1))),
      sack(assign).
        by(constant('Y')),
      sack(assign).
        by(constant('N'))
    ).
      select('crn').
    project('crn', 'cycle').by(id).by(sack())).
  fold().aggregate('x').dedup().unfold()
```

example: https://gremlify.com/6oxgibpxgne

Comment: Hello @noam621, Thanks for the solution. It is working for the particular case. However, it is not able to detect the `cycle`.  It is giving `N` for every scenario. I have edited the question, please have a look. Thank you

Comment: See another TinkerPop recipe: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#connected-components It uses the construct g.V().emit(cyclicPath().or().not(both())) for this reason!